# Counting the number of paths

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I am self-studying william Feller's Probability Theory and It's applications, and I stuck on the following problem concerned with counting the number of dyck paths satisfying a certain property.

> Let $a>c>0$ and $b>0$. The number of paths which touch the line $x=a$
> and then lead to $(n,c)$ without having touched the line $x=-b$ equals
>
> $$N_{n,2a-c} - N_{n,2a+2b+c}$$

where $N_{n,k}$ is the number of dyck paths from (0,0) to (n,k). From the reflection principle, we have the total number of paths from the origin to $(n,c)$ that touch the line $x=a$ is $N_{n,2a-c}$, and from the answer it seems we reflect that point $(n,2a-c)$ on the line $x=-b$, but I can't figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Draw/write it out. You want to exclude the number of paths that touch $a$ and then $-b$ and finally $(n,c)$.

Comment: You should say that these paths are "Dyck paths".

Comment: Besides, when you say "which touch the line $x=a$" : is it at least once or possibly several times ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Possibly several times

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks. I'm trying to draw a geometric picture like the one for the regular reflection principle, but i'm a bit lost. One idea I had was: Suppose the path passes through $x=a$ at $(k,a)$ for the first time, then I need to count the number of paths from $(k,a)$ to $(n,c)$ that pass through $x=-b$ at some point to subtract it later, there are $N_{n-k, 2b-c+a}$ such paths and then I multiply this by $N_{k,a}$ and sum over all k, but it seems there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Yes, that is what we want to do. Use the reflection principle again for that. IE Show that a path that goes from $(0, 0)$ to $(k, a)$ to $(l, -b)$ to $(n,c)$ is in a bijection with a path from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, 2a+2b+c)$, and this map can be obtained by using the reflection principle again.

Comment: We have a bijection between paths from (0,0) to (k,a) to (l,-b) to (n,c) to paths from (0,0) to (k,a) to (l,2a+b) to (n,2a+2b+2c), essentially I am reversing the sign of the components in the portion from (k,a) to (l,-b). Since every path from (0,0) to(n,2a+2b+c) has to pass through x=a and x=2a+b at some point. We have the bijection, right? Since I am only reversing the sign of one portion of the path, how is this a double application of the reflection principle?